# java.io.FileNotFoundException In Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am downloading an audio file from a remote server, and then intend to save it to storage before actually playing it on the app.
I am using the sliderbridge class to display progress, but i get this error on download complete when i try to save it to storage:

```
              java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Relevant code :

```
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          final String file=_cat+".mp3";
       if(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(file))
       {FileSystemStorage.getInstance().delete(file);};
        String path="/"+file;

               ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest() {




                    protected void postResponse() {
        try{
             String path1=FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
            String path2=path1+"/"+file;
            InputStream stream =FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(path2);
            OutputStream out = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream(file);
            Util.copy(stream, out);
            Util.cleanup(stream);
            Util.cleanup(out);
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {ex.printStackTrace();}
                    }

             protected void handleException(Exception err) {
                    Dialog.show("Network Error!!", "Are you connected to the internet? Check your connection...And Click To Start Again", "Ok", null);
                 overall.removeComponent(Welcome);
                 overall.removeComponent(sb);
                 overall.invalidate();
                 overall.revalidate();
             }
         };


         r.setUrl("http://abcde.com/images/"+file);
         r.setPost(false);

        try
      {
            sb=new SliderBridge(r);
           NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(r);
           overall.addComponent(Welcome);
           overall.addComponent(sb);
           overall.repaint();
           overall.invalidate();
           overall.revalidate();


             } 
      catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work...i used this

```
        ConnectionRequest r;
        r = new ConnectionRequest() {
        int chr;
        int size=1024;
        byte[] data = new byte[size];
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] final_dat;
        @Override
        protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        while ((chr = input.read(data,0,size)) != -1){
        buffer.write(data,0, chr);


                   }
             final_dat=buffer.toByteArray();



            }


         protected void postResponse() {

       try{

       isp=new ByteArrayInputStream(final_dat);
       OutputStream out = Storage.getInstance().createOutputStream(file);
      }
       Util.copy(isp, out);
       Util.cleanup(isp);
       Util.cleanup(out);
        }
    catch(Exception ex)
  {ex.printStackTrace();}
}
```